# How do points work in Team Fortress 2?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I've recently gotten into Team Fortress 2, and for a while now, I've been wondering how points actually work. I've noticed some servers have custom plugins that assign points to players that seem unrelated to TF2's actual point system, but **what actions earn you (official) points in the game?**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From the official TF2 wiki:

> Points are the basic scoring unit of
>   Team Fortress 2, and are awarded for
>   different successful offensive and
>   defensive actions. Performing these
>   actions will also often earn a voice
>   response from the class you are
>   playing.
>
> Points can be awarded in fractions,
>   however these will not show up on the
>   scoreboard until a whole number is
>   reached.

[Here is the complete list](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Points).